# How to limit LDA topics to terms that are distinct?

Tags: python, gensim, lda, topic-modeling

I am using `gensim` to do LDA on a corpus of arXiv abstracts in the category [stats.ML](https://arxiv.org/list/stat.ML/recent)

My problem is that there is a lot of overlap between the topics (whether I pick 5, 10, or 50 topics). Every topic has a distribution of words like "model" "algorithm", or "problem." How can topics be considered differentiable if so many of them prominently feature the same terms?

Using pyLDAvis was instructive for me . This is the distribution for topic #3:
[image: topics with lambda equal one]

But when I turn down `lambda = 0.08`, the actual nature of the topic emerges (ML in medical applications):
[image: topics with low lambda]

So my question is, how could I uncover these distinctive terms in the course of training my LDA model (without pyLDAvis)? And also, does the performance (as opposed to interpret-ability) of the model improve if I can get it to ignore these common, non-discriminating terms?

I have several ideas to try but would like more guidance:

- Filtering the 50 most common terms from my dictionary. While I think it helped a bit, I'm not sure if it's the right approach
- Tweaking `eta` parameter in `gensim.models.LdaModel`

My goal is ultimately to take a new document and do word coloring on it based on which words relate to which topics, and also offer the documents most similar to the input document.

I am pretty new with `gensim`, and this is my first SO question, so if I'm totally off-base with something, please let me know ;-). Thank you

Comment: Dear Omar, I am sorry you did not receive an answer. I am actually asking myself the same questions now, so I'd like to know if and how you were able to tweak your model to perform better. Would love to hear from you :)